# Show that P($A^c\cap B^c)\leq (1-\epsilon)^2$ for dependent distinct events A and B such that P(A)$\geq\epsilon$ and P(B)$\geq\epsilon$

Tags: probability

If two distinct events A and B are dependent such that P(A)$\geq\epsilon$ and  P(B)$\geq\epsilon$, we want to show that P($A^c\cap B^c)\leq (1-\epsilon)^2.$

Comment: Consider one flip of a fair coin and let both $A$ and $B$ be the event that a heads appears.  Thus, we may set $\epsilon=1/2.$ The event $A^c\cap B^c$ is the appearance of a tails, with probability $1/2.$ You are asking us, therefore, to show that $$1/2 = \Pr\left(A^c\cap B^c\right) \le (1-1/2)^2 = 1/4,$$ which obviously is not true.

Comment: In your example, A and B are independent. But in the question, two events are dependent.

Comment: In my example, $A$ and $B$ are anything but independent! They are identical and have probability strictly between $0$ and $1.$  Thus, $$\Pr(A)\Pr(B) = 1/4 \ne 1/2=\Pr(A\cap B)$$ shows lack of independence by definition.

Comment: @mathfear I think you misunderstood. In whuber's example, $A$ is the event that a coin flip shows heads, and $B$ is the event that the **same** coin flip shows heads. Whuber is writing about a single flip, not writing about the outcomes of 2 distinct flips.

Comment: @whuber these two events are distinct. I edited the question now.

Comment: I'm afraid that will be of no help: you should have little trouble coming up with comparable counterexamples--they only need to be slightly more complicated.  (For instance, let $B$ be the event that the coin lands heads or lands on its edge.) Are you sure this is the question you need to ask?

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align}
P(A^c \cap B^c) & = P((A \cup B)^c) \\
& = 1 - P(A \cup B) \\
& = 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B) \\
& \leq 1 - 2 \epsilon + P(A \cap B) \\
& = (1 - \epsilon)^2 - \epsilon^2 + P(A \cap B),
\end{align}
so a sufficient condition is that $P(A \cap B) \leq \epsilon^2$, i.e. the probability of the intersection must be small.  An extreme case is when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint so that $P(A \cap B) = 0$.  As whuber's comment shows, the result is not true in general and can fail when there is too much overlap between $A$ and $B$.